# Update App installed via Apple Configurator with other Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, apple-configurator

We installed iBooks through Apple Configurator to hundreds of iPad all with the same Apple ID. Now the users want to update the app but iOS is asking that Apple ID's password.

Is there a way to allow users to update iBooks with their Apple ID instead of the one which the .ipa thrown to Configurator  was downloaded with?

We didn't manually assigned the Apple ID to iBooks and when each iPad was activated we gave an individual Apple ID to each in the iCloud step but still iBooks remained signed with the Apple ID the .ipa was downloaded with

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't found a good solution for this either. We replicate all of our iPads from the same image, and we don't allow the end users to install apps, or update them. We use a syncing cart, and update from a single iTunes account from a single Mac.

Comment: well, the users are geographically far away so that's not an option either :(

Comment: If that's the case, I would have the users delete the existing install of iBooks, and reinstall it under their own ID.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't go with an MDM solution that would work remotely if you have more than 30 remote iPads. Did you supervise the devices or just use configurator for a one time load?

Comment: we were an outsourcer, the client had a mdm installed AFTER we did the initial load. the client should have installed ibooks through the mdm, we told him that but he insisted in having iBooks right away

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't have a way to do that.

However, try and delete the app and download the new version of it with user's Apple ID.

It takes the same amount of data and time as to update it.